# Versioning of a nodejs project and dockerizing it with minimum image diff

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

The npm version is located at `package.json`.

I have a `Dockerfile`, simplified as follows:

1. FROM NODE:carbon
2. COPY ./package.json ${DIR}/
3. RUN npm install
4. COPY . ${DIR}
5. RUN npm build

Correct my understanding,

If `./package.json` changes, is it true that the writable docker image layers changes are from 2 to 5?

**Assuming that** I do not have any changes on npm package dependencies,
How could I change the project version but I do not want docker rebuild image layer for `RUN npm install` ?

Comment: Indeed if `package.json` changes, the corresponding cache will be invalidated and the build will start again from step 2.

Comment: However you mention that you seldom change package dependencies (which are precisely stored in `package.json`), so most of the time (when you just rebuild a new version of the app) the build will just start from step 4. But I'm unsure one could come with an "in-between solution" you are suggesting along the lines (that is, changing `package.json` without redoing step 3).

Comment: Docker image layer at step 2 is copying package.json that has been changed (perhaps, detected by checking its hash), would that mean step 2 is invalidated and thus the build would start all over again from step 2 to step 5?

The changes of package.json is only the version.

Comment: Indeed. But I guess your use case is sensible (avoiding reinstalling all dependencies if the the `packages.json` file changed except regarding the dependencies) so I'm gonna try to come up with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, the behavior you describe using Docker is fairly standard (as soon as `package.json` has changed and has a different hash, `COPY package.json ./` will be trigerred again as well as each subsequent Dockerfile command).

Thus, the [docker setup](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) outlined in the official doc of Node.js does not alleviate this, and proposes the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:carbon

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

But if you really want to find ways to avoid rerunning `npm install` from scratch most of the time, you could just maintain two different files `package.json` and, say, `package-deps.json`, import (and rename) `package-deps.json` and run `npm install`, then use the proper `package.json` afterwards.

And if you want to have more checks to be sure that the dependencies of both files are not out-of-sync, it happens that the role of file `package-lock.json` may be of some help, if you use the new `npm ci` feature that comes with npm 5.8 (cf. the corresponding [changelog](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/v5.8.0/CHANGELOG.md#npm-ci)) instead of using `npm install`.
In this case, as the latest version of `npm` available in Docker Hub is npm 5.6, you'll need to upgrade it beforehand.

All things put together, here is a possible `Dockerfile` for this use case:

```
FROM node:carbon

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Upgrade npm to have "npm ci" available
RUN npm install -g npm@5.8.0

# Import conf files for dependencies
COPY package-lock.json package-deps.json ./
# Note that this REQUIRES to run the command "npm install --package-lock-only"
# before running "docker build …" and also REQUIRES a "package-deps.json" file
# that is in sync w.r.t. package.json's dependencies

# Install app dependencies
RUN mv package-deps.json package.json && npm ci
# Note that "npm ci" checks that package.json and package-lock.json are in sync

# COPY package.json ./  # subsumed by the following command
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

*Disclaimer:* I did not try the solution above on a realistic example as I'm not a regular node user, but you may view this as a useful workaround for the dev phase…

Comment: @Anjar I made another test and it appears that `npm ci` works smoothly even if the `version` field differs in `package-lock.json` and `package.json`... so I believe the proposed solution should address your use case.